# handeling user input to safely store it in a database and pull it back out like a cms

Tags: php, mysql, xss, sql-injection

I'm learning php by making a cms, everything went fine up to now. The next thing I want to implement is user input, more specificly I want them to be able to write their own posts, questions,.. on the site like you can on pretty much every forum.

Now here's the problem, I've read multiple articles saying you have to be careful when allowing user input because they can do stuff like sql injections and xss injections. Though I found many articles about this, I didn't found any decent tutorials/guides to solve this problem.

I dug a little bit deeper and found out you can protect your sql from injections by using *php pdo prepare statements*. Problem #1 solved!

Now onto problem #2: xss injections. I've read you have to use functions like *htmlspecialchars* and such but they never said when to use them. (Before inserting it into the database or when pulling it out of the database) I also read about HTML Purifier but that removes all js so you can't allow users to post code examples, and I realy realy need that...

If you know how I can solve the whole input security, please drop a comment/answer below. It's verry much needed and appreciated!

*NOTE: if it matters at all, the users are allowed to input their posts in markdown wich I can already convert to html with php.*

Answer (score 1):

As far as handling XSS, that's typically handled after the data is pulled back out of the database.  Instead of using another library, have a look here for sanatizing your output

[PHP Sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Specifically, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS

I should also suggest if you're trying to learn about handling security, you check into protecting yourself from XSRF attacks as well.  Here's a good write-up on what XSRF is and how to protect against it:

[Prevent XSRF](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-%28CSRF%29-Attacks-in-PHP)

Good luck! And props to you for actually doing your own research first!

Comment: Thanks for the XSRF prevention tip, I'm definitely going to implement that! But the XSS part isn't totally clear just yet... For instance: performance wise, isn't sanitizing the input and storing it into a database way faster then sanitizing every single requested pull from the database?

Comment: The performance difference, in most cases, would be very very minor.  Many frameworks (like Python's Django) which automatically sanitizes output on each request.  I think the thinking goes, that in the future if you want to handle sanitation differently or you want to allow users the freedom to enter basic HTML (like bold their own text without having to use BBCode), that will break the data already in your database because you've modified it.  If you do it at request time, then you have the freedom to change things down the road.

Comment: Yes I wan't them to be able to input basic html I've already configured MarkItUp so that users who don't know html can wtire (mainly click buttons) in markdown. The problem is once they input some code in codeblocks like some javascript HTMLPurifier just throws all of that away, leaving you with empty <code></code> tags... And ok now I store everything in the database without any conversion, if the user wan't to edit it do I echo it with htmlspecialchars() in a text input?